# Get Property after Serilog LogContext.PushProperty

Tags: .net, .net-core, serilog

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with Serilog in a Worker application, this Worker application just read from a file and make inserts in a database.

So, each time this JOB runs I'm writing a CorrelationID in Serilog, in this way:

```
LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

This works fine because I'm using `config.Enrich.FromLogContext()` in `Startup.cs`. But now I need to retrieve correlationId information from another class and I can't found any method to do it, something like: `LogContext.GetProperty(...)`

All examples that I found in my *google search* use the HttpContext, but remember that I'm in a Worker Application, so I don't have HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using Serilog.Context;
using System;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Threading;

namespace Core.Logging
{
    public static class ContextCorrelator
    {
        private static AsyncLocal<ImmutableDictionary<string, object>> _items = new AsyncLocal<ImmutableDictionary<string, object>>();
        private static ImmutableDictionary<string,object> Items
        {
            get => _items.Value == null ? _items.Value = ImmutableDictionary<string, object>.Empty : _items.Value;
            set => _items.Value = value;
        }

        public static object GetValue(string key) => Items[key];

        public static IDisposable BeginCorrelationScope(string key, object value)
        {
            if (Items.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{key} is already being correlated!");
            }
            
            var scope = new CorrelationScope(Items, LogContext.PushProperty(key, value));
            Items = Items.Add(key, value);
            return scope;
        }

        public class CorrelationScope : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly ImmutableDictionary<string,object> _bookmark;
            private readonly IDisposable _logContextPop;

            public CorrelationScope(ImmutableDictionary<string,object> bookmark, IDisposable logContextPop)
            {
                _bookmark = bookmark ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bookmark));
                _logContextPop = logContextPop ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logContextPop));
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Items = bookmark;
                _logContextPop.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```cs
using (ContextCorrelator.BeginCorrelationScope("SessionId", sessionId))
{
    var sessionId = ContextCorrelator.GetValue("SessionId");
}
```

Code from question in serilog issues
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1015